# SSRS - Programmatically update password in Data source credentials

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services

We use SQL Server 2017. Our SSRS Reports DataSource Credentials use Log into the data source "Using the following Credentials" and select "Windows user name and password".

[image]

How can I change the password here progamatically ?

The C# code below ran successfully, but when I go back to SSRS report "/MyFolder/MyReport", the password wasn't changed (I know this because I initially entered the wrong password here, and after the code runs, I go back here and click "Test Connection", and it gives me an error "Log on failed. Ensure the user name and password are correct."

```
ReportingService2010.ReportingService2010 rsClient = new ReportingService2010.ReportingService2010();
rsClient.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

CatalogItem[] items = null;

DataSource[] dataSources = rsClient.GetItemDataSources("/MyFolder/MyReport");
DataSource ds = dataSources[0];
DataSourceDefinition dsd = (DataSourceDefinition)ds.Item;
dsd.Password = "MyPwd";
```

Comment: Why post the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69110626/ssrs-programmatically-update-password-in-data-source-credentials) twice at the _same time?_

Comment: @Micky that datetime stamps are identical, would suggest a site issue rather than user.

Comment: Yup looks like it was a glitch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have much experience with the specific ReportingService2010 assembly that you are referencing, but reviewing the Microsoft documentation, it appears that you need to set the `DataSource` contents using your created `DataSourceDefinition` instance using the method `SetDataSourceContents`.

```
ReportingService2010.ReportingService2010 rsClient = new ReportingService2010.ReportingService2010();
rsClient.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
DataSource[] dataSources = rsClient.GetItemDataSources("/MyFolder/MyReport");
DataSource ds = dataSources[0];
DataSourceDefinition dsd = (DataSourceDefinition)ds.Item;
dsd.Password = "MyPwd";
/*set all other DataSourceDefinition values*/
rsClient.SetDataSourceContents("url_to_data_source_here",dsd);
```

Your current example is basically setting the `DataSourceDefinition` values and then doing nothing with them.

Complete Microsoft doc to SetDataSourceContents method [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.setdatasourcecontents?view=sqlserver-2016).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help ! This statement did the trick
rsClient.SetItemDataSources("/MyFolder/MyReport", dataSources);

Comment: And, yes, I don't think I posted the question twice, but somehow it showed up twice. Thank you for your understanding.